# How can I list Custom Post Types created with the Types plugin under categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, plugin-types

I am using the [Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/) plugin and have ticked *Categories* under the **Registered taxonomies that will be used with this post type** section.  However, no categories seem to appear.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, category and tag archives only list Posts in that category. So, despite the UI appearing on the backend, the posts don't show up in the archives. Luckily this isn't too hard to solve.

Look at [this support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-tagscategories-archive-page?replies=40) and [this answer in particular](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-tagscategories-archive-page?replies=40#post-1786990). It has resolved this issue for me in the past. Make sure not to use the first few code snippets in the thread as they interfere with menus.

You may also want to look into Justin Tadlock's post: ["Showing custom post types on your home/blog page"](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/02/02/showing-custom-post-types-on-your-home-blog-page).

Comment: Ah, thank you so much, this is what solved my issue: http://tinypaste.com/7b8c7a7c